# Triple boot Ubuntu, Kali and Tails from USB with persistent home directories

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, kali-linux, liveusb, tails

I would like to have a USB flash drive from which I can boot live systems of Ubuntu, Kali Linux and Tails OS with all of them having a persistent part, where I can save settings and files to. If it is possible it would be very nice to use the same directories so I don't have to have everything multiple times on the flash drive, but if this is not possible, I can live with it. I know that it is possible to have all three operating systems installed to seperate flash drives with persistent partitions for their data, but I would rather like to have one flash drive that I can use to boot whatever OS I need at the moment.

Comment: I use VMware on a fast SSD drive and have multiple systems (simultaneously) that way.  Kali (in Kali now), Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: So you boot from an internal drive, or is the SSD drive external? Can I achieve my wanted setup with this?  And if so, could you explain in more detail how to set it up?

Comment: I use VMware to make virtual machines on my built-in SSD main drive.

Comment: I do use virtual machines in Windows Hyper-V as well, but first I don’t get Tails to work, and second the problem I face is that I can’t use the hardware acceleration I would like to have in some applications, especially video transcoding. And I only have the machines available on my home laptop, but I would like to be able to use the preinstalled system with all my stuff from the usb wherever I go with whatever pc I have at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: install Debian on a flash drive (since you want ubuntu)

Step 2: build your os with any features and programs you want.

The repositories and git hub have all the Tails and Kali things you want. That's the beauty of Linux, you can mishmash everything together to build your system however you want. Just get a basic Ubuntu iso then boot in and *`sudo apt-cache search Kali`* (or x desired package) to find the Kali toolkit then install and look up a guide on the Linux wiki for routing all networking through tor like tails does also you can add the tails packages you want with the command line above. this way you only get the stuff you want/need on one single system instead of having to switch out constantly. also look into using ram as your /swap since having a /swap on the usb will degrade it faster.

EDIT*
Or Option B: get YUMI exFAT from **[pendrivelinux.com](https://www.pendrivelinux.com)** and install all 3 using that it will add the persistence for each and you can add your own .iso or let YUMI download one for you